# How to render a React component on redux state change?

Tags: reactjs, redux, socket.io

I am using this [redux-socket.io](https://github.com/itaylor/redux-socket.io) middleware to dispatch actions from the server on socket.io requests. This part works fine, all the stuff I needed until now, I could do with this.

Now I am trying to use this middleware to dispatch an action that sets a piece of state, then I would like to render a React component (basically a floating window, above everything else) when the state contains a specific key.

The problem is, after dispatching the action, I am not sure how to make React render a component on state change. (Above the currently rendered component)

Since I want to render this component above everything else, I don't think it would be a good idea to check for updated props in every single component I have.

I thought about using the subscribe API but I haven't found any examples of rendering a component from inside there.

What would be the best solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the state in your return for the render with something like a ternary operator and if true, then render the popup.

`{state === correct ? <PopUp/> : null}`

Every time state changes, the page is dynamically re-rendered.

Comment: How do I make it so I don't have to check in every single component I have? I can't connect to props in App.js, right?

Comment: I am not quite understanding what you mean with the props. But you can pass the state as props too if you wish to check for the pop-up in a subcomponent. Maybe provide more details about what exactly is it that you are working with?